# ASP Script not accepting PNG

Tags: asp-classic

I think this code

```
For Each file in filecoll
    Ext = UCase(Right(File.Path, 3)) 
    If Ext = "JPG" OR Ext = "GIF" Then
    on error resume next
```

allows only JPG files to be displayed, is there anyway to add PNG and GIF so the script will display these also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're already set for .gif files, presumably you can change the line

```
If Ext = "JPG" OR Ext = "GIF" Then
```

to read

```
If Ext = "JPG" OR Ext = "GIF" OR Ext = "PNG" Then
```

and all will be well.*

* that said, it's 2012 and you're working on an ASP classic project, so perhaps not.